# Can we set Annotation id at runtime

Tags: java

Is there a way by which I can set the `id` inside annotated method...

Annotation class:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public
@interface MyAnnotation {
    int id();
}

//Set id at runtime
public class A {
    @MyAnnotation(id = ? )
    public void method1() {
        // I want to set the id here for my annotation...

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it's a bit unintuitive. You'll have to edit its bytecode using a tool like JavaAssist.

Here is an [article](http://ayoubelabbassi.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-add-annotations-at-runtime-to.html) describing what you're after.

Comment: Thanx it helped.. i was using javasist but was not aware of how to use the addAnnotation()....  :)

Comment: If that was the correct answer, please mark it so. Thanks!

Comment: Yes.. Its working perfectly fine for me.. Now I am able set annotations at runtime..Thanx